# How to send back result to the calling method from Activity

Tags: java, android

I am developing reusable component for android platform.

my requirement is something like this : 
user will call below method 'getValue()' which in Activity 'A'. From 'getValue()', I am launching Acivity 'B' and in its 'onCreate()' method only I can build value for 'result'.
Now I have to pass this(result) to the caller.

Below is the code template:

User will call like this:

```
 String val = getValue();
```

This will be my code:

```
 Activity A{

 public static String getValue(){
 Intent i = new Intent(this, B.class);
 startActivity(i);

 return result;

}
}
```

This is my Activity B:

```
Activity B{

protected void onCreate(){

result = a*b;

}
}
```

Please let me know how can pass value here.

I tried startActivityForResult(), this doesnt work because it will return value to the caller activity(Which is Acivity A) and I can't change the user code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How send result to back to previous activity in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526771/how-send-result-to-back-to-previous-activity-in-android)

Comment: You can also view this question already answered :

[How send result to back to previous activity in android?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526771/how-send-result-to-back-to-previous-activity-in-android

Answer (score 0):

check doc for the [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) method.